# How to get crowdsale info via API?

Tags: etherscan, python, crowdsale

I need get info about crowdsale.

By example, [here](http://paragoncoin.com/), there is information about the number of tokens sold, Hardcap and so on. This information, as indicated on the site, is updated every 60 seconds.

I need to get the same information to display on the website, but I do not understand where to get it.

Example of information:

> PRESALE (SOLD OUT) - 70,000,000
>
> PRG TOKENS SOLD (CROWDSALE) - 3,550,921
>
> PRG Hardcap - 30,000,000 PRG

I understand that I need to use https://etherscan.io/apis, but having studied the majority of methods, it seems none of them gives me the necessary information.

Comment: You want to display information about your own crowdsale or any crowdsale?

Comment: At the moment, I want to use any of the available crowdsales, in order to prepare API methods, after which, it will be needed for my.

Answer (score 1):

The total supply can be obtained as follows::

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

We receive all transactions for this smart contract.:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c&offset=10000000000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

The sum of all the `value` in this txlist is the sum of the released tokens.